# Get All total value inside the child value Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have create school database on the firebase, I want to sum all the same keys of the one school. Like School1 have Subject key , inside Subject have students : name1, name2 , etc and each student have same subjects "AAA" , "BBB" , "CCC", now I want to sum of the subject "AAA", Can you help me how can sum of the value "AAA" keys

```
{
    "School1": {
        "Subject": {
            "Name1": {
                "AAA": 50,
                "BBB": 60,
                "CCC": 70,
                "DDD": 80
            },
            "Name2": {
                "AAA": 50,
                "BBB": 60,
                "CCC": 70,
                "DDD": 80
            },
            "Name3": {
                "AAA": 50,
                "BBB": 60,
                "CCC": 70,
                "DDD": 80
            }
        }
    },
    "School2": {
        "Subject": {
            "Name1": {
                "AAA": 50,
                "BBB": 60,
                "CCC": 70,
                "DDD": 80
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output result of AAA:**

School1:
AAA : 150

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for a single query that gives you the sum? Realtime Database doesn't have any aggregation queries like that.  You will have to query the nodes and sum them up yourself.

Comment: @DougStevenson So that I have to looping for it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to go about it.

DatabaseReference aaa = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("School1").child("Subject");

```
    aaa.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            int sum = 0;
            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                sum = (int) child.child("AAA").getValue()   + sum;
            }

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Total Sum is "+ sum, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Please let me know if it helps you.

Comment: Great answer Martin! Please don't ignore the `onCancelled` though. Even a minimal implementation can save lots of future problems: `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`

Comment: Thank you Frank. I've been ignoring the onCancelled method in all of my Firebase code. I will now be adding the exception.

Comment: @MartinMbae Can you give answer in javascript.